# Picture in the title page of custom beamer theme

Tags: beamer

I am using [this](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/presentations/modern-beamer-theme-(mtheme)?&nocdn=true) theme but I can't add a picture in the title page. The following command doesn't work.

```
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Image}}
```

Why doesn't it work? How can I add the picture?

```
\documentclass[10pt, compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{m}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\usemintedstyle{trac}

\title{Presentation Title}

\author{Author 1\inst{1} \and Author 2\inst{2}}

\date{}

\institute[UP]{\inst{1} Institute 1 \and \inst{2} Institute 2}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}

 Text here

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a compilable example which does not depend on external links. Remember that your question should be self-contained (unless absolutely impossible) so that it can be understood by future users, even if the link content changes or disappears. Moreover, relying on links makes it much harder for people with the same question to find this one as there is much less to search for.

Comment: @cfr It is impossible to provide a MWE as the theme is custom, so the link is necessary for people to find the files needed to activate it. There is no way to upload the files here.

Comment: I find no evidence in the documentation at https://github.com/matze/mtheme to suggest that `\titlegraphic` is supported by the theme. Beamer provides this command, but the theme has to use it when defining the relevant template. Given that the theme aims for minimalism, I would guess that it is not designed to support this. (What is it meant to do? I've never used it.)

Comment: You can provide an MWE which uses the theme and a link to the source for the theme, which is on GitHub and not ShareLaTeX. How are you trying to use this? Where? There is nothing in the theme's manual about it at all.

Comment: @cfr I will edit my question but why it is better to use the GitHub link and not the ShareLaTeX one? As to how I used it, I opened it in ShareLaTeX which provides all the necessary files. That is why I used that link as you can download all the files necessary.

Comment: It should work, looking at the code.

Comment: I don't want to register with ShareLaTeX or figure out ShareLaTeX's approach. And I want to know that I've got the latest version, with any bug fixes so I don't waste time on a problem which has already been solved upstream. And I want the documentation provided by the theme's author(s) and not ShareLaTeX's interpretation of it.

Comment: @cfr I know but the command doesn't even produce an error or warning...It is just ignored.

Comment: @cfr I used that too I just didn't write it here as I wrote that MWE quickly. It didn't work...

Comment: Ignore me. I think I'm wrong.

Comment: @cfr No worries. At least you tried. :)

Comment: The version you are using is from October 2014. The current version is from March 2016. I suspect you just have an outdated version and need to get the current one, which works fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, unlike OverLeaf, I can't view the files without registering for ShareLaTeX, which I don't want to do. But using an outdated version is not a good idea in any case, even though I can't look at the code to know whether it is responsible for this particular problem.

Comment: The initial release of version 1.0 seems to post-date the creation of the template on ShareLaTeX. Which version of the theme do you have? Current is 1.1.

Comment: @cfr I don't know. I will check it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using upstream's code from GitHub, it works fine when I use `metropolis` as the theme's name.

```
\documentclass[10pt, compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\title{Presentation Title}

\author{Author 1\inst{1} \and Author 2\inst{2}}

\date{}

\institute[UP]{\inst{1} Institute 1 \and \inst{2} Institute 2}

\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=.25\textheight]{cathod}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}

 Text here.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: title graphic on title page]